# Xamarin iOS CallKit Prompt Input on Incoming Call

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, callkit

Is there a way that i can prompt the user (on an incoming call) for input using `CallKit` in `Xamarin iOS`?

For instance, if I wanted to prompt a caller (on an incoming call) to press a button and then store the call and the button pressed - is that possible? I can see the `CallKit` documentation where it talks about handling incoming calls, but I am not sure how to prompt a caller for input.

I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: No, the standard incoming call dialog can't accept input. If the call is coming in to your own voip app then you can do what you want in your own apps interface.  You cannot find out any information about other incoming calls.

Comment: my understanding is that with CallKit, I can capture the incoming call, thus making it come to my voip app, right? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: You can handle incoming calls to your voip app,  but you can't direct arbitrary calls to your app. Ie you can't intercept cellular calls or other voip app calls

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding exactly. Can I direct all calls to my VOIP app? Then, for instance, if the number is in my contacts, prompt them to input a number?

Comment: No, you can't. You can only receive calls from your voip server in your app. It would be a major privacy violation if your app could receive information about incoming calls

Comment: How does an app like https://www.robokiller.com/ work then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162273/discussion-between-paulw11-and-blubberbo).

Comment: @blubberbo: Can you please share the AppDelegate.cs and ViewController.cs please?

Comment: @YumYumYum I haven't written any code specific to solving this problem yet - I am more just asking if it is possible

Comment: You cant modify it. Its only a middle man receiver and linking to your APP.

Comment: Paulw11 is correct on it, that is the answer actually : "standard incoming call dialog can't accept input"